# Copy formula from Google Sheets, paste as formula in TextEdit

Tags: google-sheets

How can I copy formulae (like `=D3`) from a *range of cells* (several rows and/or columns), and paste those formulae (not the values) somewhere in like TextEdit or anywhere else?

Normally it will just paste the data.
I want to avoid manually selecting each formula one by one, as it takes a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to do that, you can either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> or select from the menu *View > Select all formulae*. Now you are able to select the range you want to copy.

### Screenshot

*menu*
[image]

*before*
[image]

*after*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jacob Jan Tuinstra's answer is still great, but Google moved some of their menu items.
It's now under `View` → `Show` → `Formulas`.